# Connect Codeigniter to Oracle 11g

Tags: codeigniter, oracle11g

I can't connect codeigniter to Oracle.
I am trying to connect Codeigniter to Oracle 11g, here are my settings

```
Settings in database.php:

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "//localhost/";
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'orcl';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Note: I added the C:\instantclient_11_2 to environment variable to PATH.

```
oracle port number:
oracle hostname: Home-pc
database name: orcl
```

Only when I run my CodeIgniter login code it shows this error message:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

But I can connect to Oracle when I run a simple php code like:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx","");
if (!$conn) { 
   echo "Not connected!";
}
else
  echo "yahooooooooo!!!!!!!!!!";
?>
```

Result:
yahooooooooo!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried leaving the hostname just as `localhost` ie. without the slashes?

Answer (score 5):

In your config's database.php make the following changes

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';

$db['default']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
$db['default']['username'] = 'XXXXXX';
$db['default']['password'] = 'XXXXX';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash, Actually this might have worked. I solved the problem by uninstalling the oracle full version and replacing it with the express version. It worked with the same settings

Answer (score 2):

change **default** to **XE**

```
$active_group = 'XE';
$active_record = TRUE;

$tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';

$db['XE']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
$db['XE']['username'] = 'XXXXXX';
$db['XE']['password'] = 'XXXXX';
$db['XE']['database'] = '';
$db['XE']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['XE']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['XE']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['XE']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['XE']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['XE']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['XE']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['XE']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['XE']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['XE']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['XE']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this changes
change the hostname to `http://localhost:1521:orcl`
you are given database name as `orcl` , by default `orcl` is default instance id.
try to create new user or database and change it in to the configuration `database`.

Comment: Thanks Abin, this might be a good solution but sorry I didn't have the chance to try it. I uninstalled Oracle Full version i was using and replaced it with the express version , it worked with my settings

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `php_oci8_11g.dll` extension is loaded in `php.ini`

Comment: Yeah, the extension is loaded.